# RxJS Observable.fromEvent chain firing for each subscriber

Tags: javascript, events, rxjs, observable

I've made a key service for a keyboard-driven interface, and I've found that it seems to execute the full chain for each subscriber:

```
this.documentKeyEvent = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
  .do((e: KeyboardEvent) => console.log(e.keyCode || e.which))
  .filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => !isKeyModified(e) && !!Keys[remap(e.keyCode || e.which)])
  .do((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.preventDefault())
  .throttle(() => Observable.timer(100))
  .map((e: KeyboardEvent) => remap(e.keyCode || e.which));
```

The `console.log` in the first `.do()` executes three times because there are three subscribers. This isn't necessarily a problem, but seems like that would get pretty inefficient as more components subscribe to it.

Is there a way to only execute that chain once per event, and then push those results to all the subscribers to then do whatever they want with?

Thanks

Comment: You can [publish](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/publish.html) it. But note that you also need [Connect](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html) or [RefCount](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html).

Comment: Or use [`share`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share)

Comment: Nice. *This is an alias for .publish().refCount()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can either use [`share`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share) as your last operator:

```
this.documentKeyEvent = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
  .do((e: KeyboardEvent) => console.log(e.keyCode || e.which))
  .filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => !isKeyModified(e) && !!Keys[remap(e.keyCode || e.which)])
  .do((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.preventDefault())
  .throttle(() => Observable.timer(100))
  .map((e: KeyboardEvent) => remap(e.keyCode || e.which))
  .share();
```

This will essentially share the stream between all subscribers.

Note: `share` is an alias for `publish().refCount()` - see the docs for details on: [`publish`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-publish)